# Confguring subdomains on a webserver

Tags: mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, web-hosting

I am in the process of setting up a website and I am facing a few difficulties. The following is my configuration.

1. EC2 instance with Tomcat installed. Elastic ip attached to EC2 instance. I can access the website by going to `http://Elastic-IP-Address/folder-name` and `http://Elastic-IP-Address/different-folder-name`

Now I have a domain name and would like to create subdomains and point them to the specific folders on the server i.e.

```
http://sd1.my-domain-name.com should point to http://Elastic-IP-Address/folder-name/
http://sd2.my-domain-name.com should point to http://Elastic-IP-Address/different-folder-name/
```

Currently, I set up the @ & WWW host as an A record to Elastic-IP-Address. I can go to `http://my-domain-name/folder-name/` and access the website correctly. When I click on a link, it shows up correctly as `http://my-domain-name/folder-name/link-i-clicked`.

Now I would like to associate the same behavior to the sub-domain setup as well. I have four record type options for associating a subdomain to the ip address in my domain registrar - A type, URL frame, URL redirect and CName.

1. I can't use A record since I want to point the subdomain to
   my-ip-address/folder/. I can only use the A record to point to
   pure IP address.
2. I can't use the URL redirect option as it changes the display of the URL from `http://sd1.my-domain-name.com` to `http://Elastic-IP-Address/folder-name/` as soon as I enter the browser url.
3. I can't use the URL Frame option as it only shows a static address and doesn't follow the links I click in the web application i.e. after clicking a link, the browser url display will stay as `http://sd2.my-domain-name.com` instead of changing to `http://sd2.my-domain-name.com/link-i-clicked` which is what I would want ideally.
4. I don't think I can use CName in this scenario.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the Apache HTTP server (which is different than Apache Tomcat)?

Answer (score 0):

DNS servers do not support (or are even aware) of paths (everything that is not the *domain name*).

What your registrar offers are not native DNS record types, but it internally points to a redirect server or a forward server.

I can suggest that you use CNAME to point all of your subdomains to the same server, and let your *web server* to find out from which sub-domain the request came, and dispatch it from there.

Here is how if you run [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) or [IIS](http://help.sana-commerce.com/en-us/commerce/sana_commerce/sana-commerce-81/configuration/multiple_domains_and_websites/configure-multiple-domains-in-iis-7)